# unfamiliar icon in github

Tags: github, icons

Hi I'm really confused about this situation.
Here is the img

[image: img]

What is the meaning of the icon in front of the `champ` and `cham_teleop` icon?
I cannot open them on github and I cannot commit any changes I made in those two repos.
I'm always new to GitHub and not too familiar using this tool for nearly 2 years.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is a gitlink, that is a nested Git repository folder.

That happens when you add a folder which has its own .git subfolder: the parent rpeository record that folder, but not its content (since it is a Git repository)